# Why does it produce two MsgBox'es?

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

I tried both of the following code, and it gives me the same result. That **yes** button, produces another MsgBox then click yes again before closing, while **no** button works perfectly well. How can I fix this problem?

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    'Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Quit?", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    'If result = DialogResult.No Then
    '    Application.Exit()
    'Else
    '    e.Cancel = True
    'End If

    Select Case MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Quit?", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            Application.Exit()
        Case MsgBoxResult.No
            e.Cancel = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see where `MsgBoxResult` came from, but this should work:

```
Dim MsgBoxResult As DialogResult 
MsgBoxResult = MessageBox.Show( _
                   "Are You Sure You Want To Quit?", _
                   Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

Select Case MsgBoxResult 
    Case DialogResult.Yes
        ' Do nothing - let it close!
        'Application.Exit()
    Case DialogResult.No
        e.Cancel = True
End Select
```

Or glue it together:

```
Dim MsgBoxResult As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Quit?", 
        Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
```

By calling Application.Exit you were invoking a new FormClose event before this one completed.  Provided this is a MainForm, just let the application close normally.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this also**

```
e.Cancel = (System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Quit?", Me.Text, Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
```